# The ScrollViewer automatically changes its height and does not scroll

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my program, I use `ScrollViewer` to display elements inside, but the problem is that when the `ScrollViewer` is filled with content, its height automatically changes and it becomes impossible to scroll since the height is equivalent to the content. I put a `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid` and it automatically stretches to its full height `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`. I can't pre-limit its height because its height automatically adjusts to its parent to fill all the space. **How can I solve this?**

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" RowSpacing="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="35"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="35"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="notesContent" Loaded="NotesContent_Loaded" Margin="0,0,15,0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <AddDeleteThemeTransition>
                            </AddDeleteThemeTransition>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: For this to work as you want, the context for the ScrollViewer must have, at some point, a set height.  Otherwise the ScrollViewer, and everything else, will just expand as you see. Please provide this context in order to determine where a set height is missing / needed.

Comment: Any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> The ScrollViewer automatically changes its height and does not scroll

The ScrollViewer parent is Grid, and you have set it's VerticalAlignment proeprty as Stretch, it will vertically fill into grid. And it is by design, you can refer to Grid [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid?view=winrt-22000).

And if you want to make ScrollViewer scrollable, you need to make the content large than ScrollViewer actual height, and the better way is specific height value for [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer?view=winrt-22000).